# NGINX, PHP, FastCGI and Windows 10 - No Input File Specified

Tags: php, nginx, server

I am attempting to setup NGINX on Windows to serve a PHP application. I am receiving a `No input file specified` message. This appears to be a common issue; however, none of the solutions I saw (both on StackOverflow and elsewhere) have resolved my difficulties.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
  index  index.html index.html index.php;
     # root   c:/Users/Kelly\ Marchewa/workspace/Code/MidAmCorp/out;
    root c:/www;

        location / {       

        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
           # include fastcgi.conf;
        }

    }


}
```

What I have tried/done:

- Placed both index and root within the `server` block.
- Tried including fastcgi.conf
- Specified `SCRIPT_FILENAME` as `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` instead of hardcoding it.
- Multiple root paths (over concerns that I made a typo or the presences of spaces was proving problematic)

These actions seem to cover the potentially applicable solutions I found. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Just as test, I tried explicitly coding the path for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` instead of `$document_root` and it worked. However, this is not ideal. What might cause this behavior?

Comment: What did you hard code it as?